# easiest way to read/write to google app engine

Tags: java, string, google-app-engine

I can't figure out how to save and read data using google app engine. This code does not compile but should give you an idea of what I want to do. The only thing that I can't seem to figure out is how to create my own key from a string....

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();


    Entity article = new Entity("Article", "keyThatIMadeUp");

    article.setProperty("articleHTML", "this is where the article html goes");


    datastore.put(article);
    try {
        Entity articleRetrieved = datastore.get(Key("keyThatIMadeUp"));
    }
    catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("data not found");
    }
```

Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys embed the type of entity that they're a key for. So to reconstruct a key from parts, you need to provide the name of the Entity type. In your case, you're looking for something like

```
... = datastore.get(Key.from_path("Article", "keyThatIMadeUp"))
```

Comment: @DaveWSmith is correct but a few notes ... = myvar then myvar will be assigned the key of the object.  As in `myvar = datastore.get(Key.from_path("Article", "keyThatIMadeUp"))`

Comment: Ended up going with this: Key k = KeyFactory.createKey("Article", "keyThatIMadeUp");
   Entity articleRetrieved = datastore.get(k);

Answer (score 0):

Try following along with the ndb overview.  It has a simple example you can follow.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/overview